# post request in nodejs without frontend

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a node application. To test out some logic I go to browser and make request for a specific routes. It is good way in case of 'get request' but what to do in 'post request'.

Comment: You can use any add-ons like as postman, RESTClient, HttpRequester, etc for http requst of get, post, put, delelte, etc for check nodejs api request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any HTTP client like [`Postman`](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [`Insomnia`](https://insomnia.rest/) or just [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Eg.:

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use postman to send post request

The Interface of Postman is changing acccording to the updates.

So You can get full information about postman can get Here.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image: for sending json use raw for direct input set key value]

use postman  if you don't understand this youtube will give you awnser